# API cache in PWA generated by Create React App v4

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

[This](https://github.com/cra-template/pwa/blob/master/packages/cra-template-pwa-typescript/template/src/service-worker.ts) is the template using `cra-template-pwa-typescript`. How do I cache external APIs and Images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c-r-a` v4 uses a model in which you have complete control over your Workbox-powered service worker file.

The general guidance on caching in the Workbox docs should help: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests

To give a concrete example, let's say you wanted to cache all cross-origin images with a stale-while-revalidate strategy. You could do that by adding this route to your service worker file:

```
registerRoute(
  ({request, url}) => url.origin !== self.location.origin &&
                      request.destination === 'image',

  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'cross-origin-images',
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size the
      // least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);
```